# convert to JSON in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, string, variables, hash

I have the following lines in a text file and iterate using File.foreach.  I want to create a JSON format of these.  How do I code that? As I print the hash, the Camaro overwrites Mustang info.

```
#textfile#
Blue   A   Mustang
Red    B   Camaro   

File.each("textfile") di |line|
  fields = line.split
  field1 = fields.first
  field2 = fields.[1]
  field3 = fields.last
  puts field1
  puts field2
  puts field3
  myhash['color'] = field1
  myhash['parkingspot'] = field2 
  myhash['car'] = field3 
end
```

Thanks in advance!
Jake

I tried pushing to hash

Comment: I presume the `di` is a typo in your question rather than your code?! How do you expect you json data to look?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have a `Hash` called `myhash` with three indices, `color`, `parkingspot`, and `car`. You iterate over each line of the file and each time you are overwriting the values of these three indices.
Instead, we can make an `array` of the cars, each containing such a `Hash`. We can then use the `JSON.generate` method to convert the cars array into a JSON string like so:

```
require 'json'

cars = []

File.foreach("textfile") do |line|
  fields = line.split
  car = {}
  car['color'] = fields.first
  car['parkingspot'] = fields[1]
  car['car'] = fields.last
  cars << car
end

puts JSON.generate(cars)
```

which outputs `[{"color":"Blue","parkingspot":"A","car":"Mustang"},{"color":"Red","parkingspot":"B","car":"Camaro"}]`

edit:
If you want a `Hash` of hashes with `parkingspot` as the key for each car, you could do the following:

```
require 'json'

cars = {}

File.foreach("textfile") do |line|
  fields = line.split
  car = {}
  car['color'] = fields.first
  car['car'] = fields.last
  cars[fields[1]] = car
end

puts JSON.generate(cars)
```

which outputs `{"A":{"color":"Blue","car":"Mustang"},"B":{"color":"Red","car":"Camaro"}}`

Comment: Thank you @steev.  How do I achieve this format? {"A":[{"color":"Blue","car":"Mustang"}],"B":[{"color":"Red","car":"Camaro"}]}

Comment: I updated the answer to output a Hash of Hashes, but in your comment, you have an unnecessary array wrapped around the attributes of each car.